# multiple iteration using dataframes to perform calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to python.

how do i multiple iteration with dataframe in pandas

I have 8760 values of sun zenith values---->theta_z
8760 values of sun azimuth values---->theta_a

Now I have to iterate for two conditions

1)panel tilt (0-90)---> theta_t
2)panel azimuth (0-360)----->theta_azi

I have to perform the below calculation

```
x=arccos(cos(theta_z)*cos(theta_t)+sin(theta_z)*sin(theta_t)*cos(theta_a-theta_azi))



for (i=0,i<8761,i=i+1)  
    for (j=0,j<361,j=j+1)  
          for (k=0,k<91,k=k+1)  

                   x=....
```

Instead of using the below loops,how do i do the iteration in pandas if I have them as a seperate dataframe for each of them.I need to get 8760 x 361 x 91 values or 361 x 91 sets of 8760 values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'zenith': [0.0, 15.0, 30.0],
    'azimuth': [0.0, 10.0, 20.0]
})
print(df)
#    zenith  azimuth
# 0     0.0      0.0
# 1    15.0     10.0
# 2    30.0     20.0
```

you can

```
import numpy as np
```

and then, for any given values of `theta_z` and `theta_a` (in radians), e.g.

```
# Data from 2nd row of the dataframe
theta_z, theta_a = np.deg2rad(df.iloc[1])
```

it will be possible to use `numpy.meshgrid` instead of looping over the `tilt` and `azimuth` values and compute the `x` values as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# Take one of the rows of the dataframe
theta_z, theta_a = np.deg2rad(df.iloc[1])

# Create the desired ranges for tilt and azimuth
range_theta_t_deg = np.arange(0.0, 91.0, 1.0)
range_theta_t = np.deg2rad(range_theta_t_deg)

range_theta_azi_deg = np.arange(0.0, 361.0, 1.0)
range_theta_azi = np.deg2rad(range_theta_azi_deg)

# Create a grid of tilt and azimuth values with the specified ranges
theta_t, theta_azi = np.meshgrid(range_theta_t, range_theta_azi, sparse=True)

# Compute x for each point in the grid, and convert back to degrees if needed
x_rad = np.arccos(np.cos(theta_z) * np.cos(theta_t) +
                  np.sin(theta_z) * np.sin(theta_t) * np.cos(theta_a - theta_azi))
x = np.rad2deg(x_rad)
```

This results in an array of shape `(361, 91)`, and the same idea can be applied to any of the 8760 rows of the original dataframe.

```
print(x)
# [[15.  14.0162433  13.03490594 ... 73.23529277 74.23419621 75.23311039]
#  [15.  14.01316484 13.02829452 ... 73.19070162 74.18981137 75.18892988]
#  [15.  14.01040734 13.02237082 ... 73.15075884 74.150054 75.1493561]
#  ...
#  [15.  14.02335841 13.05017949 ... 73.33835117 74.33678044 75.335225]
#  [15.  14.01964157 13.04220205 ... 73.28451547 74.28319197 75.2818814]
#  [15.  14.0162433  13.03490594 ... 73.23529277 74.23419621 75.23311039]]
```